# Robotium plugin installation problem in the android studio

Tags: robotium

Hello sir Good Afternoon,
I was not able to see the robotium plugin in the Android studio

Moreover While i am trying to install Robotium plugins from the internet,I am getting this issue

**Not compatible with the version of your running IDE (Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1)
**
May i know Which version will support robotium plugins in android studio and is there any other alternative to install the robotium in the Android Studio

I have tried installing robotium in the Android Studio moreover i was failed to do this,Can anyone suggest any alternatives are any other processes for the installation